# Trying to display all posts in a category

Tags: categories, loop

I want to display all post with its own category. I tried but the loop is fetching all existing categories. Here is my code:

```
<?php //query to echo the categories 
 $cat_counts = wp_list_pluck( get_categories(),'count', 'name' );?>
   <?php foreach ( $cat_counts as $name => $count ) {?>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><?php echo $name;?></a>
       <a href='#' class='pull-right'><?php echo sprintf( "%02d", $count ) ;?></a><br/>
     </li>
```

Comment: You mean sort posts by their category?

Comment: Yes.thats what i want @blackhawk

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried so far, but below you have a quick answer to list posts from a caategory by its ID.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, // Will show all posts from the category
    'cat'              => 149, // ID of the category
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => array('publish')
); 

$posts_list = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts_list as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <article>
        <li>
        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
        <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>   
        <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        Category: <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'category', '', ' ' ); ?>
        </li>
    </article>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following codes.I hope it will work.

```
<?php 

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, array('Your category name') );
$term_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );     
$args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'your post  name' ), //
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category name',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_slugs
                )
    );


    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```